# Getting counts from a dataset based on conditions created from another dataset

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
Primary   col1   col2   
nex1    nex2    nex3    
nex2    nex1    nex3    
nex3    nex1    nex2
```

I want to loop over this dataset for each rowxcol  combination and  count all cases e.g. where (nex1>=1 and nex2>=1) in another dataset(data_y) which contains these nex1-nex3000 variables. Then move to second case(data_x) where (nex1>=1 and nex3>=1) until the end of row.
Now go to the second row of and repeat, til the end of row. So data_x is just to get all the possible cases. I want to get the count for these cases from another dataset data_y

Data_y is like this:

```
nex1 nex2 nex3.....nex3000
1     0    1     3
0     0    0     0
3     1    0     1
1     2    1     0
0     0    1     0
```

So final dataset will be having counts for these cases(each case from data_x for rowxcol combination).

```
 col1   col2...
  2      2
  2      1
  2      1...
```

so pseudo code is like this:

```
for each primary in data_x:
     for each col in data_x:
        select count(*) from data_y where &primary_val>=1 and &col_val>=1
```

example first case:

```
 first primary in data_x(is nex1):
         first col in data_x(nex2):
               select count(*) from data_y where nex1>=1 and nex2>=1
```

this produces for first case in output dataset col1: 2( there are 2 cases in data_y where the first primary x col condition is satisfied)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of your second data set and output example that can be reproduced?

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to piece this together for your expected output. What have you tried so far? Do you have some initial code to start it off?

Comment: i updated the question, hopefully it is clear now

Comment: @muni slightly clearer - but there's still not a self-contained data of input for both datasets and expected output that someone can pick up and run and check...

Comment: ok, i updated the example dataset, that can be matched for counts in final dataset

Comment: Maybe walk us through getting the first row in the final dataset, (explain the process, step by step) like: the value of the first item (row1/col1) of data_x is ```nex1```, use ```nex1``` in data_y to *?do what?*.

Comment: i updated along with pseudo code, an example case